# Feller-Torier constant equals this sum involving the prime zeta function?

Tags: zeta-functions, constants, euler-product

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller%E2%80%93Tornier_constant) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Feller-TornierConstant.html) pages, the Feller-Tornier constant can be defined by this sum involving the prime zeta function
$$C_{\text{FT}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\exp\left[-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n P(n)}{n}\right]\right)$$

When I evaluate this, I get $1/2$ because of the divergent sum, not $0.6613170494\ldots$ as it should be.

Both Wikipedia and Mathworld give this formula.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo, they meant 
$$\log \prod_p (1-\frac{2}{p^2}) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\frac{P(\color{red}{2}n)}{n}$$

Comment: Just edited the Wikipedia